# Error message: Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: vb.net

I don't know why when ever I click on the update button, I get an error

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement

I have no idea what's going wrong in my code

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Function vld(ByVal ParamArray ctl() As Object) As Boolean
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(ctl)
            If ctl(i).text = "" Then
                ErrorProvider1.SetError(ctl(i), ctl(i).tag)
                Return False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        cn.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TxtExamtime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        TxtExamtime.CustomFormat = "hh:MM tt"
        cn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; Data Source=C:\psave\New folder\save.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
        cn.Open()
        FillDataGridView("select ID, Family Name, Given Name, Gender, DOB, Exam Date, Exam Time, Street Name, House Nr, PLZ, City from [edit$]")

    End Sub

    Private Sub FillDataGridView(ByVal Query As String)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, cn)
        dt.Clear()
        da.Fill(dt)
        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = dt
            .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Family Name"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Given Name"
            .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Gender"
            .Columns(4).HeaderText = "DOB"
            .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Exam Date"
            .Columns(6).HeaderText = "Exam Time"
            .Columns(7).HeaderText = "Street Name"
            .Columns(8).HeaderText = "House Nr"
            .Columns(9).HeaderText = "PLZ"
            .Columns(10).HeaderText = "City"
            .Columns(10).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
        Try
            FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$] where ID='" & TxtId.Text & "'")
            TxtFamilyname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
            TxtGivenname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
            TxtGender.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
            TxtDob.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
            TxtExamdate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
            TxtExamtime.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
            TxtStreet.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
            TxtHouse.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
            TxtPlz.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(9)
            TxtCity.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(10)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
        If vld(TxtId, TxtFamilyname, TxtGivenname, TxtGender, TxtDob, TxtExamdate, TxtExamtime, TxtStreet, TxtHouse, TxtPlz, TxtCity) = False Then
            Exit Sub
        Else

        End If

        Try
            With cm
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "insert into [edit$]values('" & TxtId.Text & "','" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "','" & TxtGivenname.Text & "','" & TxtGender.Text & "','" & TxtDob.Text & "','" & TxtExamdate.Text & "','" & TxtExamtime.Text & "','" & TxtStreet.Text & "','" & TxtHouse.Text & "','" & TxtPlz.Text & "','" & TxtCity.Text & "' )"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
            Return
        End Try
        MsgBox("succefully Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnupdate.Click
        Try
            With cm
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Update from [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where ID ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and Given Name = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "' and Gender = '" & TxtGender.Text & "'and DOB = '" & TxtDob.Text & "'and Exam Date'" & TxtExamdate.Text & "'and Exam Time = '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "'and Street Name = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "'and House Nr = '" & TxtHouse.Text & "'and PLZ = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "'and CITY = '" & TxtCity.Text & "'"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
            Return
        End Try
        MsgBox("Succesfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
        TxtId.Clear()
        TxtFamilyname.Clear()
        TxtGivenname.Clear()
        TxtStreet.Clear()
        TxtHouse.Clear()
        TxtPlz.Clear()
        TxtCity.Clear()
        'To see all the data in DataGridView
        FillDataGridView("select * from[edit$]")

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDelete.Click
        Try
            With cm
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Delete from [edit$] where [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' and ID ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and [Given Name] = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "'and Gender = '" & TxtGender.Text & "'and DOB = '" & TxtDob.Text & "'and [Exam Date]'" & TxtExamdate.Text & "'and [Exam Time] = '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "'and [Street Name] = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "'and [House Nr] = '" & TxtHouse.Text & "'and PLZ = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "'and CITY = '" & TxtCity.Text & "'"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("Succesfully Deleted!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
            FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should take notice of what the message is telling you and check the syntax of your `update` query. `UPDATE FROM...` is not valid syntax.

Comment: ***Where*** in all that code does the error happen?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 4):

An Update statement does not have a "From" in it, so it should start with...

```
    Update [Edit$]
```

There's a couple of other things wrong too. If the ID is a number then it probably doesn't need bounding single quotes, through they won't stop it either...

```
    Where ID = " & txtId.text & "
```

Columns names that have embedded  white space need bounding brackets...

```
    and [Given Name] = '" & txtGivenName.text & "'
```

Finally, this statement is wide open to SQL Injection, where someone could do serious damage to your table by entering SQL into one of your text boxes. Please consider using parameters instead.

You should also consider using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as the one you are using is quite old now.

You should probably have other parameters in your extended properties if you want to use Excel as a database, in particular you will need HDR=Yes...

```
    Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"""
```

This tells OLEDB that the first line of your sheet contains the column names, otherwise it will use F1...Fn (I think but it may be C1...Cn)

Comment: Am using an excel sheet to save my data

Comment: Yes.I missed that. well bounding quotes around the ID won't hurt I suppose. I'd love to give this a go myself but I don't have anything here to try it.

Comment: Still showing an error as "Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression". Don't know what is wrong in my code

Comment: Izaz, it's kinda hard to tell without you posting your new code. If you do can you pause execution in debug after you've filled your CommandText and post it's value as well.

Comment: i cant post it in comment box its too long to post my new code

Comment: you can amend your question to include it.

Comment: Solved it :D 


 .CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name]= '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "',[Given Name] = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "',[Gender] = '" & TxtGender.Text & "',[DOB] = '" & TxtDob.Text & "',[Exam Date] = '" & TxtExamdate.Text & "',[Exam Time] = '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "',[Street Name] = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "',[House Nr] = '" & TxtHouse.Text & "',[PLZ] = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "',[CITY] = '" & TxtCity.Text & "' where ID = '" & TxtId.Text & "' "

Answer (score 2):

Beside some other issues with your code (e.g. you should almost always use parameterized queries), `Update from [edit$] set...` is wrong.

Just use `Update [edit$] set...`.

Answer (score 1):

**Your Syntax for Update statment is clearly not correct :**

**please find below code :**

```
 Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnupdate.Click
        Try
            With cm
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where ID ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and [Given Name] = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "' and Gender = '" & TxtGender.Text & "'and DOB = '" & TxtDob.Text & "'and [Exam Date]='" & TxtExamdate.Text & "'and [Exam Time]= '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "'and [Street Name] = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "'and [House Nr]= '" & TxtHouse.Text & "'and PLZ = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "'and CITY = '" & TxtCity.Text & "'"
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
            Return
        End Try
        MsgBox("Succesfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
    End Sub
```

**Place all column names inside [ ] other wise the query will be interpreted wrongly because it might ignore the rest of the query as soon as it encounters a white space**

You have done it correctly for family name but certainly ignored other column names which have a space in between them

Comment: Now its showing an error message as "Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression"

Comment: @Izaz..there are few other issues with your code , as Ciaran has mentioned . place all your columns names which have space in between them . Ex : Exam time , house num etc.

Comment: Still showing an error as "Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression". Don't know what is wrong in my code

Comment: You missed some spaces betwen semicolon and `and`word  E.g: `...TxtGender.Text & "'and DOB...`.  It should be `...TxtGender.Text & "' and DOB...`