# Error message in UPDATE statement: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: vb.net

I don't know why when ever I click on the update button, I get an error
Syntax error in UPDATE statement

I have no idea what's going wrong in my code

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
 Private Function vld(ByVal ParamArray ctl() As Object) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(ctl)
        If ctl(i).text = "" Then
            ErrorProvider1.SetError(ctl(i), ctl(i).tag)
            Return False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function

Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    cn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TxtExamtime.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    TxtExamtime.CustomFormat = "hh:MM tt"
    cn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; Data Source=C:\psave\New folder\save.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    cn.Open()
    FillDataGridView("select ID, Family Name, Given Name, Gender, DOB, Exam Date, Exam Time, Street Name, House Nr, PLZ, City from [edit$]")

End Sub

Private Sub FillDataGridView(ByVal Query As String)
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, cn)
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    With DataGridView1
        .DataSource = dt
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Family Name"
        .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Given Name"
        .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Gender"
        .Columns(4).HeaderText = "DOB"
        .Columns(5).HeaderText = "Exam Date"
        .Columns(6).HeaderText = "Exam Time"
        .Columns(7).HeaderText = "Street Name"
        .Columns(8).HeaderText = "House Nr"
        .Columns(9).HeaderText = "PLZ"
        .Columns(10).HeaderText = "City"
        .Columns(10).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
    Try
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$] where ID='" & TxtId.Text & "'")
        TxtFamilyname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
        TxtGivenname.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
        TxtGender.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
        TxtDob.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
        TxtExamdate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
        TxtExamtime.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
        TxtStreet.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
        TxtHouse.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
        TxtPlz.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(9)
        TxtCity.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(10)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BtnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    If vld(TxtId, TxtFamilyname, TxtGivenname, TxtGender, TxtDob, TxtExamdate, TxtExamtime, TxtStreet, TxtHouse, TxtPlz, TxtCity) = False Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

    End If

    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "insert into [edit$]values('" & TxtId.Text & "','" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "','" & TxtGivenname.Text & "','" & TxtGender.Text & "','" & TxtDob.Text & "','" & TxtExamdate.Text & "','" & TxtExamtime.Text & "','" & TxtStreet.Text & "','" & TxtHouse.Text & "','" & TxtPlz.Text & "','" & TxtCity.Text & "' )"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("succefully Saved!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnupdate.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where [ID] ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and [Given Name] = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "' and [Gender] = '" & TxtGender.Text & "'and [DOB] = '" & TxtDob.Text & "'and [Exam Date]'" & TxtExamdate.Text & "'and [Exam Time] = '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "'and [Street Name] = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "'and [House Nr] = '" & TxtHouse.Text & "'and [PLZ] = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "'and [CITY] = '" & TxtCity.Text & "'"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
        Return
    End Try
    MsgBox("Succesfully updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
End Sub

Private Sub BtnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClose.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnClear.Click
    TxtId.Clear()
    TxtFamilyname.Clear()
    TxtGivenname.Clear()
    TxtStreet.Clear()
    TxtHouse.Clear()
    TxtPlz.Clear()
    TxtCity.Clear()
    'To see all the data in DataGridView
    FillDataGridView("select * from[edit$]")

End Sub

Private Sub BtnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDelete.Click
    Try
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandText = "Delete from [edit$] where [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' and [ID] ='" & TxtId.Text & "' and [Given Name] = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "'and [Gender] = '" & TxtGender.Text & "'and [DOB] = '" & TxtDob.Text & "'and [Exam Date]'" & TxtExamdate.Text & "'and [Exam Time] = '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "'and [Street Name] = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "'and [House Nr] = '" & TxtHouse.Text & "'and [PLZ] = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "'and [CITY] = '" & TxtCity.Text & "'"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MsgBox("Succesfully Deleted!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)
        FillDataGridView("select * from [edit$]")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, Text)

    End Try


End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: The syntax error very likely tells you exactly what the problem is with your syntax. That's what the error is for.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025617/error-message-syntax-error-in-update-statement/30025723

Comment: Why are you using different users to post the same question? Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025617/error-message-syntax-error-in-update-statement/30025723

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:

```
.CommandText = "Update [edit$] set [Family Name] = '" & TxtFamilyname.Text & "' where ID = '" & TxtId.Text & "' and [Given Name] = '" & TxtGivenname.Text & "' and Gender = '" & TxtGender.Text & "' and DOB = '" & TxtDob.Text & "' and [Exam Date] = '" & TxtExamdate.Text & "' and [Exam Time] = '" & TxtExamtime.Text & "' and [Street Name] = '" & TxtStreet.Text & "' and [House Nr] = '" & TxtHouse.Text & "' and PLZ = '" & TxtPlz.Text & "' and CITY = '" & TxtCity.Text & "'"
```

Changes I made:

- Added spaces in between values and the AND keyword (for example, `TxtExamdate.Text & "'and [Exam Time]` needs a space before "and")
- Added missing equal signs between field names and values (for example, `and [Exam Date]'" & TxtExamdate.Text` should look more like `and [Exam Date] = '" & TxtExamdate.Text`)
- Got rid of extraneous brackets

If you still have problems, consider that you are inserting strings (which could potentially contain any printable character (and non-printable characters!) from textboxes, directly into your statement. If these strings contain illegal characters (for example, single or double quotes) they will change the meaning of your UPDATE statement, and possibly invalidate the syntax. It has been suggested before (in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025617/error-message-syntax-error-in-update-statement#comment48168707_30025617)) that you should use [parametrized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx). Finally, you may get a Data Type Mismatch error if any of your table columns are not strings (like "ID"), because you're sending them all as strings (enclosed in double quotes).

And please, only post a question once, from a single account.